# Groovy Removing Quotes in String Parameters

Tags: groovy, dsl, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to implement a simple DSL for scheduling events. I will have to put "schedule meeting" without quotes in a closure, and it should schedule a meeting. "schedule appointment" will schedule an appointment, etc. However, I cannot get rid of the quotes in my closure, as it registers 'meeting' as a property, and gives me `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: meeting for class: groovy.SchedulerTest`.

I know we can mark the function with "infix" in Kotlin, but not exactly sure how I could simulate that in Groovy.

Here is the class for DSL:

```
class Scheduler {
  //var meeting = "meeting" //I could uncomment this and it would work, but then I would need to create a new variable for every type of meeting
  String type

  def static create(closure) {
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler()
    closure.delegate = scheduler
    closure()
    return scheduler.print_values()
  }

  def schedule(String type) {
    this.type = type
  }
  
  def print_values() {
    return "${this.type} scheduled"
  }
}
```

Here is the test case I am trying to pass:

```
class SchedulerTest extends Specification {

  def "Scheduler Type Test"() {
    setup:
    String type_test = Scheduler.create {
      schedule meeting //it runs just fine if I write -> schedule "meeting". But I am not allowed to use any quotes as my requirements.
    }

    expect:
      type_test == "meeting scheduled"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test would pass if you added the following method to the `Scheduler` class:

```
def propertyMissing(String propertyName) {
    propertyName
}
```

Comment: The requirements are not clear but if you only want to support specific property names, you could of course add some logic to `propertyMissing` to return the `propertyName` under certain circumstances and throw `MissingPropertyException` under others, that would work.  Another approach is to define specific properties in `Scheduler` that you want to support and assign them values, like `String meeting = 'meeting'`, in which case you wouldn't need `propertyMissing`.